# How do you add an ActionListener onto a JButton in Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton, actionlistener

```
private JButton jBtnDrawCircle = new JButton("Circle");
private JButton jBtnDrawSquare = new JButton("Square");
private JButton jBtnDrawTriangle = new JButton("Triangle");
private JButton jBtnSelection = new JButton("Selection");
```

How do I add action listeners to these buttons, so that from a main method I can call `actionperformed` on them, so when they are clicked I can call them in my program?

Answer (score 68):

Two ways:

**1.** Implement ActionListener in your class, then use `jBtnSelection.addActionListener(this);`  Later, you'll have to define a menthod, `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)`.  However, doing this for multiple buttons can be confusing, because the `actionPerformed` method will have to check the source of each event (`e.getSource()`) to see which button it came from.

**2.** Use anonymous inner classes:

```
jBtnSelection.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
    selectionButtonPressed();
  } 
} );
```

Later, you'll have to define `selectionButtonPressed()`.
This works better when you have multiple buttons, because your calls to individual methods for handling the actions are right next to the definition of the button.

**2, Updated.** Since Java 8 introduced lambda expressions, you can say essentially the same thing as #2 but use fewer characters:

```
jBtnSelection.addActionListener(e -> selectionButtonPressed());
```

In this case, `e` is the ActionEvent. This works because the ActionListener interface has only one method, `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)`.

The second method also allows you to call the `selectionButtonPressed` method directly.  In this case, you could call `selectionButtonPressed()` if some other action happens, too - like, when a timer goes off or something (but in this case, your method would be named something different, maybe `selectionChanged()`).

Comment: @Sara - Glad that helped! If you can think of any further clarifications, I'll be happy to add them to this answer.

Comment: When someone asks: How can a component handle its own events?
is the answer to that question to use anonymous inner classes like you here showed?

Comment: Not necessarily. You could have a custom component (e.g., something that extends JComponent) and also implements ActionListener, MouseListener, etc.

Comment: Don't you have to add @Override for actionPerformed?

Comment: You don't *have* to, but it's a good practice to do that. Using Override is a good practice because it helps you recognize when you think you've implemented a method from the super class or interface, but really you've given your function an incorrect method signature. But using Override is not required when writing a Java program.

Comment: Java 9 is forcing me to use @override, or declare it as a lambda function\

Comment: @DavidKoelle - So, what are the disadvantages of using multiple if(ev.getSource()) statements all in one actionPerformed() method? Will it slow down your program a lot? Or is it for readability? Thanks.

Comment: Readability, extensibility, and maintenance. Imagine you're going to remove an existing button - now you have to remember to remove code from multiple places. Or if you're going to add a new button, you're adding functionality to multiple places. Also, you're having to do a lot of, "If it's this source, do this; if it's that source, do that" and that's not very object-oriented. The object should know how to do its thing without other code being involved.

Answer (score 8):

Your best bet is to review the [Java Swing tutorials](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/ui/index.html), specifically the [tutorial on Buttons](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html).

The short code snippet is:

```
jBtnDrawCircle.addActionListener( /*class that implements ActionListener*/ );
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this works but I made the variable names

```java
public abstract class beep implements ActionListener {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("beeper");
        JButton button = new JButton("Beep me");
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(300, 200);
        f.add(button);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // Insert code here
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer "non-magic" lambdas, by which I mean where the type of the argument(s) are explicitly specified such as (***ActionEvent*** e) -> instead of just e ->:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
JButton addBtn = new JButton("Add");
addBtn.addActionListener((ActionEvent ae) -> 
    addBtnClicked(nameField.getText(), occupationField.getText()));

private void addBtnClicked(String name, String occupation)
{
    if(name.length() == 0 || occupation.length() == 0) return;
    System.out.format("Name: %s, Occupation: %s%n", name, occupation);
}
```