# How do I add a listener in a GUI jButton?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, onclicklistener

```
    JButton bkButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon("src/Images/smallBArrow.bmp"));
    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    buttonPanel.add(bkButton);
```

Using an action listener I need to be able to click and have an action (to go back, forward, or refresh)

Answer (score 5):

This is usually done with an anonymous inner class...

```
bkButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
        backButtonPressed();
    } 
});
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284899/how-do-you-add-an-actionlistener-onto-a-jbutton-in-java) answer

Comment: especially useful if this is a to-be-used-once action. If you will share a single action across several components, you should declare it as an ActionListener reference, then assign.