# Setting functions to individual buttons

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have a soundboard program I am designing for school. I'm actually permitted to write whatever program that I want. I have a code written for it, as shown here:

```
package soundboard;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Soundboard implements ActionListener{

JButton loadButton;
JButton clearButton;
JButton Button1;
JButton Button2;
JButton Button3;
JButton Button4;
JPanel mainsPanel;
int load;

public void windowCreate() {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    mainsPanel = new JPanel();


    loadButton = new JButton("Load...");
    loadButton.setSize(80, 30);
    loadButton.setLocation(4, 4);
    loadButton.addActionListener(this);

    clearButton = new JButton("Clear");
    clearButton.setSize(80, 30);
    clearButton.setLocation(92, 4);
    clearButton.addActionListener(this);


    Button1 = new JButton("1");
    Button1.setSize(80, 80);
    Button1.setLocation(4, 45);
    Button1.addActionListener(this);

    Button2 = new JButton("2");
    Button2.setSize(80, 80);
    Button2.setLocation(92, 45);
    Button2.addActionListener(this);

    Button3 = new JButton("3");
    Button3.setSize(80, 80);
    Button3.setLocation(4, 133);
    Button3.addActionListener(this);

    Button4 = new JButton("4");
    Button4.setSize(80, 80);
    Button4.setLocation(92, 133);
    Button4.addActionListener(this);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.add(loadButton);
    frame.add(clearButton);
    frame.add(Button1);
    frame.add(Button2);
    frame.add(Button3);
    frame.add(Button4);
    frame.add(mainsPanel);

    frame.setSize(183,245);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);                
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
    load += 1;
    System.out.println(load);        
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Soundboard window = new Soundboard();
    window.windowCreate();
}


}
```

In this example, every single button does the exact same thing. How, using this base code, ca I set it so the buttons do their own individual thing? I plan on designing it so hitting the "load" button and then a number-button loads a sound to that said button. Hitting a number-button without hitting load first plays the previously designated sound. Hitting "clear" unloads all buttons.

Comment: Write your own [anonymous ActionListener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/284899/how-do-you-add-an-actionlistener-onto-a-jbutton-in-java) instead of implementing it like this. Soundboard should not be an ActionListener. Instead it can be a JPanel.

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. "Button1" should be "button1".

Comment: KK, I actually know that - just missed that there. Thanks for the reminder camickr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
ButtonX.addActionListener(this);
```

write

```
ButtonX.addActionListener(e -> {
        //do stuff here
    });
```

The `->` signifies that this is a lambda expression, which basically creates an anonymous class from a functional interface and passes it as an argument. For more on lambda expressions, you can read my guide [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21974187/2846923), or the official (but long) tutorial [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).

After you make all the lambda expressions, you can remove the

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
    load += 1;
    System.out.println(load);        
}
```

and

```
 implements ActionListener
```

from your class.

Comment: This actually is quite helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need to attach different action performed to seperate button an e.g. on how to do it is below for load and clear button

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Soundboard implements ActionListener{

JButton loadButton;
JButton clearButton;
JButton Button1;
JButton Button2;
JButton Button3;
JButton Button4;
JPanel mainsPanel;
int load;

public void windowCreate() {


    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    mainsPanel = new JPanel();


    loadButton = new JButton("Load...");
    loadButton.setSize(80, 30);
    loadButton.setLocation(4, 4);
    loadButton.addActionListener(e -> System.out.println("load action"));

    clearButton = new JButton("Clear");
    clearButton.setSize(80, 30);
    clearButton.setLocation(92, 4);
    clearButton.addActionListener(e -> System.out.println("Clear action"));


    Button1 = new JButton("1");
    Button1.setSize(80, 80);
    Button1.setLocation(4, 45);
    Button1.addActionListener(this);

    Button2 = new JButton("2");
    Button2.setSize(80, 80);
    Button2.setLocation(92, 45);
    Button2.addActionListener(this);

    Button3 = new JButton("3");
    Button3.setSize(80, 80);
    Button3.setLocation(4, 133);
    Button3.addActionListener(this);

    Button4 = new JButton("4");
    Button4.setSize(80, 80);
    Button4.setLocation(92, 133);
    Button4.addActionListener(this);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.add(loadButton);
    frame.add(clearButton);
    frame.add(Button1);
    frame.add(Button2);
    frame.add(Button3);
    frame.add(Button4);
    frame.add(mainsPanel);

    frame.setSize(183,245);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);                
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
    load += 1;
    System.out.println(load);        
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Soundboard window = new Soundboard();
    window.windowCreate();
}


}
```