# How to load data into set of jbuttons from the database

Tags: jbutton

I want to load my food items int to a set of jbuttons. I have come this far

```
 static JButton j;
 jPanel3.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 5, 3, 3));
 jPanel3.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
       for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            j = new JButton();
            j.setText(i + "");
            jPanel3.add(j);
                 }
```

but i want to get individual source of the button. i only get the last button source. anybody know how do to this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to define j as an array of JButtons. Afterwards you can use j as an Array.
Here is a link where you can see how Arrays work :
[JavaDocsTutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

```
 static JButton[] j = new JButton[10];
 jPanel3.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 5, 3, 3)); 
 Panel3.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      j[i] = new JButton();
      j[i].setText(i + "");
      jPanel3.add(j[i]);
 }
```

The code is untested, but it shows where to make changes.

Comment: @javaDocs  Thanx for your help mate but can u tell me how to add an event to that?

Comment: Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/284899/how-do-you-add-an-actionlistener-onto-a-jbutton-in-java