# How can I add to the quantity variable every time the user clicked the button?

Tags: java, swing

I have two `JFrame` in my GUI.

One is `order` frame and another is `payment` frame.

I would like to add onto the `quantity` variable every time when the user clicked on the `button`. I have added the increment-logic under the button method, but it seems only applicable in that method only. It won't add `+1` into my array variable.

Here is my code for this:

```
class Bun extends javax.swing.JFrame {
 String decimal = "0.00";
 DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(decimal);
 public final String [] bname = new String [] {"Tuna Sandwich","Garlic Bread","Redbean Bun"};
 public final double [] bprice = new double [] {1.20, 1.50, 1.50};
 public double [] bsub = new double [9];
 public int [] bquantity = new int[]{0,0,0};
 public double bsubtotal;

private void BtnTunaSandwichActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
    bquantity[0]++;
    numTunaSandwich.setText(Integer.toString(bquantity[0]));
}                                               

private void BtnGarlicBreadActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
   bquantity[1]++;
   numGarlicBread.setText(Integer.toString(bquantity[1]));
}                                              

private void BtnRedbeanBunActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
   bquantity[2]++;
   numRedbeanBun.setText(Integer.toString(bquantity[2]));
}                      

public void calculatesub()
{
    for(int counter=0;counter<bsub.length;counter++)
    {
        bsub[counter]=bquantity[counter]*bprice[counter];
    }
}
public void setsubtotal()
{
    for(int counter=0;counter<bsub.length;counter++)
    {
        bsubtotal += bsub[counter];
    }
}
public String getsubtotal()
{
    return (df.format(bsubtotal));
}
```

This is my Payment frame code:

```
private void subtotalActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        Bun bun = new Bun();
        bun.calculatesub();
        bun.setsubtotal();
        subtotal.setText(bun.getsubtotal());
}
```

Whenever I run the program and try to calculate the subtotal, it shows `0`.

My interface:

[image: Order Frame]
[image: Payment Frame]

Comment: Where do you call `calculatesub` ?

Comment: I think you might need to change the `bquantity[0]++` to `bquantity[0] = bquantity[0] + 1` - I think `++` means increase it by 1 and return the old value, but `bquantity[0] = bquantity[0] + 1` means increase it by 1 and return the new value.

Comment: You need to hold the `bquantity` object in a single class. Maybe both JFrames have there own objects? Probably there are two `=new int[3];`

Comment: @Berger I call it in my another frame

Comment: What @Berger said: where do you call `calculatesub()` and `setsubtotal()`? You have the methods but I don't see you actually **using** them anywhere. Also from what I can see `calculatesub()` will go out of bounds.

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors I call them in my Payment frame, that's what other people told me for pass the value.

Comment: @JoopEggen No I didn't declare anything in another frame

Comment: @Thraydor It makes sense but its not working...

Comment: Two problems in your code: bsub should be 3 elements long, not 9. And in  `setsubtotal()` you are not resetting `bsubtotal` to 0 before you add to it.

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors The bsub is actually my mistake in this post, there are actually 9 arrays in my code. But that's too long so I cut short for the post. I have test the method in another class and its working. So it must be the bquantity problem...

Comment: @SilverArcher Well... we need to see how you set up the two frames then because it is obviously there that your problem lies. Also, I am noticing that your action listeners are `private` which means that the other frame cannot be calling them. Append your code to show up how you set up the two frames and pass a reference of this one ("Bun") to the other.

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors Edited and add my interface, thanks

Comment: @SilverArcher Ok, you cannot make a **new** `Bun` every time you press the subtotal button. Because then you have two instances of `Bun`; the one that is already showing, and the new one. You are asking for the subtotal from the new one (that is invisible because you have not set it to visible). You need to pass a reference of the previously created `Bun` and use **that** in your `subtotalActionPerformed`.

Comment: @SilverArcher It might seem simple, but have you added the action listener to your buttons for the menu selections?

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors But I thought the Bun bun = new Bun is the object ? For let this class have access to another class.

Comment: @Thraydor Is it the Event -> Action -> ActionPerformed ? I have done that to every button and write the bquantity[arraynumber]++ under it.

Comment: @SilverArcher Well we can't see your declared buttons/fields etc. So you have done `BtnTunaSandwich.addActionListener(...)` for the buttons?

Comment: @SilverArcher "Bun bun = new Bun is the object ?". Yes, that is your problem. You do **not** want to call methods on a **new** object, you want to call it on the old one that already exists and that is showing on your screen! :)

Comment: @Thraydor Uh, I think not. Just this one: private void BtnTunaSandwichActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
    bquantity[0]++;
    numTunaSandwich.setText(Integer.toString(bquantity[0]));
}

Comment: @SilverArcher Have a read of this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/284899/how-do-you-add-an-actionlistener-onto-a-jbutton-in-java - you need to add listeners to the buttons. They need a link.

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors Okay but after I delete this line it gives me cannot find symbol error on bun.calcualtesub, bun.setsubtotal and bun.getsubtotal.

Comment: @SilverArcher ...which is why I said you need to pass a reference of your previously created `Bun` object to your Payment Frame.

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors Is it okay if I write something like this in the Payment frame ? Bun bun;
    public void setBun(Bun bun)
    {
        this.bun = bun;
    }

Comment: That should do it, yes. So then you do new Bun, new Payment, payment.setBun (bun).

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors I wrote new bun, new payment and pay.setBun(bun) in the Order Frame, right ? Then should I call that method in Payment frame ?

Comment: @SilverArcher How are the listeners coming along? Without a listener attached to the button there won't be any code that is activated when you click it

Comment: @Thraydor I'm learning it from some youtube video and some post, its a new thing to me haha, thanks for your help !

Comment: @SilverArcher You're welcome. Once you have the action listener in for one of the food buttons, it's easy enough to test it works just by keep clicking the button, and then you can just copy the code across to the other buttons for their listeners. There are multiple ways to do it (as shown on the link I gave), you just need to decide which suits your program better.

Comment: @SilverArcher This has some information on buttons and using listeners also - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#abstractbutton

Answer (score 0):

You need to have field in your class like

public int qvantity=0;

And increse this every time wheb someone click on button and you need again to set text on jlabel if you use it for represent quvantity all that you need to have on method for click button

Update: Or you can create one method which will increse qvantity and set text to label which you use. And this method you need to call in actionPerformed

Update 2: Did you try to setText of subtotal textField when you click on some of button. You can try with some method which will calculate all order, and then call that method on payment button, that method will return some int and that int you need to use in setText of subtotal textField, I realy don't know why you use txtField for it.

Comment: Yes i have the field as array. I increased it by adding the bquantity[]++ under the button actionPerformed method.

Comment: But you need to increase bguantity[0] not array

Comment: I increased it by adding the bquantity[arraynumber]++ under every button actionPerformed.

Comment: wait i will try to do it

Comment: in method calculateSub you need to setText of yout txtField

Comment: But the method calculateSub is not the one I want to display in the textField, in the method setsubtotal, the bsubtotal is the one I want to display in the textfield...

Comment: you use too much method and it's so confused, when you calculate how many orders you have you need that number to display in txtField

Answer (score 0):

change your bsub length to 3 instead of 9.

Comment: That's my mistake on this post in my code there are actually 9 arrays.

Comment: Try initialize your bsubtotal to zero.