# How I can cause that program wait until press start button in Java?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm making a game in Java with Swing. I created a start menu. I want the game to start when I press the start button.

I have a start button in my startScreen object. I want to add game object to my frame when I press.

I try very bad way:

```
while(startScreen.isVisible()){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Core.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }window.add(gameScreen);
```

What is the true way?

Comment: i dont see the usage of any button anywhere. Why do you use sleep?

Comment: Instead of making the program wait, why not start the function when the button is pressed?

Comment: Without knowing much regarding your code structuring, you want to make sure your program's main loop is in a method that gets called when you select the start button. Any specific details would require further information on your part about your program's structuring and classes.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284899/how-do-you-add-an-actionlistener-onto-a-jbutton-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what type of 'button' you're referring to, your implementation may change.  But, for example, using a `JButton`, you could register some action to do *when the button is pressed*.  Something like:

```java
button.addActionListener(event -> {
    // Do whatever it is that you're wanting to do in here...
    System.out.println("The button was pressed...");
});
```