# How can I use two buttons instead of JOptionPane.showOptionDialog?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, joptionpane

So it works correctly but it is a bit confusing I would like to remove JOptionPane.showOptionDialog and simply add 2 buttons so that it is not so confusing in the code.............

I have tried with JButtons but could not make it
And more than anything that fulfills the function of throwing the result

How can I use two buttons instead of JOptionPane.showOptionDialog?

```
float n, r;
int a = 1;
String input;

//Button content
Object[] options1 = {"°C -> °F", "°F -> °C", "Exit"};

int menu = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, a + ". Select your conversion",
    "Temperature scale selection",
    JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
    null, options1, null);
//Button 2
if (menu == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
    //Celsius to Fahrenheit
    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter degrees Celsius: ");
    n = Integer.parseInt(input);
    r = ((9 * n) / 5) + 32;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, r + " Fahrenheit");
} else if (menu == JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION) { //Button 3
    //Fahrenheit to Celsius 
    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter degrees Fahrenheit ");
    n = Integer.parseInt(input);
    r = (n - 32) * 5 / 9;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, r + " Celsius");
}
```

Comment: Is one of the overloaded [`showConfirmDialog()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showConfirmDialog-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-) methods not suitable?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a couple of JButtons to just display, that in itself is a bit of a process. To get one to display, you're going to need a `JFrame` and a `JPanel`. Once you have those two, you can add a new `JButton` to your `JPanel`. Adding multiple buttons and swing components requires the use of a layout for your `JPanel`. You can read more about [how to use JPanels](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html), [examples of using JPanels](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-swing-jpanel-examples/), and [layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html#border).

After you have your buttons displayed on your panel, you have to add an `ActionListener` to each button so that it can perform the desired action. You can take a look at the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) or [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284899/how-do-you-add-an-actionlistener-onto-a-jbutton-in-java) for information on how to write one.

Getting buttons and other swing components basic functionality is a bit of a process, but it's the most basic way of achieving what you want.